# Extract all lines including the line which contains the substring and lines after the substring in python

Tags: python

I am running into problems where I am trying to extract the lines after including the line from where the substring exist.

```
s="""
   This is so awesome
   I need to do this more often
   This forum rocks
   Help me
  """
```

If the substring I search is **forum**, I want to get the result as

```
   this forum rocks
   Help me
```

I tried using the following statement

```
s.lower().split("forum",1)[1]
```

and my output is

```
forum rocks
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **hint:**  first, try to find the *line* which contains the word forum.

Comment: Do the lines have a hidden `'\n'` in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-line solution with `re.search()` function:

```
import re

s="""
   This is so awesome
   I need to do this more often
   This forum rocks
   Help me
  """    
result = re.search(r'.*\bforum[\s\S]*', s, re.M).group()
print(result)
```

The output:

```
   This forum rocks
   Help me
```

Comment: Going on based on your answer would this solution be also used yo cut out the text before the line "forum" ?

Comment: I was now trying to extract the lines above the line that contains the word "forum". Example- The output would contain only "This is so awesome I need to do this more often"

Comment: @ayushman999, use this `result = re.search(r'(.*)(?=\n.*\bforum[\s\S]*)', s, re.M | re.S).group(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to split the string by line, and search each line for the word you want.

```
s="""
This is so awesome
I need to do this more often
This forum rocks
Help me
""".split('\n')
for line in range(len(s)):
    if "forum" in s[line]:
        print(s[line])
        print(s[line+1])
```

As long as the multi-line string ends on the next line after the last line with text in it, you won't go out of bounds for the list. If you have the last `"""` on the previous line, next to `Help me`, you'll have to do a range check.

EDIT: Re-read the question. You want *all* lines after the word forum is found? The previous example I gave just gets you the *next* line. For all lines after the key word is found, use this:

```
s="""
This is so awesome
I need to do this more often
This forum rocks
Help me
""".split('\n')
found = False
for line in range(len(s-1)):
    if "forum" in s[line] or found:
        print(s[line])
        found = True
```

The `len(s-1)` part is optional. Depending on whether you want the trailing blank line included in the results. If you want that last blank line, just change it back to `len(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will work for a string containing any number of lines.

```
s="""
   This is so awesome
   I need to do this more often
   This forum rocks
   Help me
  """
s=s.split('\n')
c=0
for i in s:
    if i.find("forum")!=-1: #  no match, find returns -1
        print "\n".join(s[c:])
    c+=1
```

Output :

```
This forum rocks
Help me
```

So, basically you find the index in the array where your match has been found and then return everything after that (by joining with a `\n` as was the case in the original string).

Answer (score 1):

```
l = s.split('\n')
for n, str in enumerate(l):
    if 'forum' in str:
        print ('\n'.join(l[n:]))
        break
```

Output:

```
   This forum rocks
   Help me
```